# constexpr function with pointer variable

Tags: c++, constexpr

To avoid having to calculate the same values manually I made a constexpr function that does it for me:

```
void constexpr pixelToTexCoords(unsigned char pixelX, unsigned char pixelY, float* texCoords) {

    texCoords[0] = pixelX / 16.f + 1 / 32.f;
    texCoords[1] = pixelY / 16.f + 1 / 32.f;

}
```

The values of pixelX and pixelY are always known in compile time, but the pointer 'texCoords' isnt.

Will this function still calculate the values in compile time?

Comment: `constexpr` only tells the compiler that the function can be evaluated at compile time with constexpr parameters. When the value of `textCoordinates` is only know at runtime naturally you can only call the function at runtime

Comment: If you're using C++20 you could use consteval that will only result in compile time evaluation and will not compile if that's not possible. In this case you could make constexpr functions for PixelX and PixelU calculations and at least that part will be evaluated compile time.

Comment: Why not return `std::pair<float, float>`?